# Error when split files by code c

Tags: c++, file, join, split

I'm coding a program which split files, but I got some problem when run it, and  I don't know how to resolve it.
Give me some intruction. All files that split sometimes 0kb, sometimes have data. It confused me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char *fn = new char[250];
    char *nfn = new char[250];
    long int size, n, size_per_pack;
    FILE *f, *ft; //file and temp file

    printf("enter the file you want to split with full path : ");
    scanf("%s", fn);
    printf("enter the number of parts you want to split the file : ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    f = fopen(fn, "rb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("couldn't open file");
        exit(0);
    }

    fseek(f, 0, 2);
    size = ftell(f);
    printf("the size of the file in bytes is : %ld\n", size);

    size_per_pack = size / n;
    rewind(f);
    int m = 0;
    char *s1 = new char[size_per_pack];
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        sprintf(nfn, "%s.%d", fn, j);
        ft = fopen(nfn, "wb");
        fread(s1, 1, size_per_pack, f);
        fwrite(&s1, 1, size_per_pack, ft);
        rewind(ft);
        int present = ftell(f);
        int present2 = ftell(ft);
    }
    delete[]s1; 
    delete[]fn; 
    delete[]nfn;
    _fcloseall();
}
```

Comment: That's _pure C++_, not C!

Comment: Is there a reason you use e.g. `char *fn = new char[250];` instead of `char fn[250];` or `std::array<char, 250> fn;`, or the best: `std::string fn;`?

Comment: A more interesting question is why are you writing C code in C++?

Comment: I just use dynamic array, the rest of it is C

Comment: Since when is fread and fwrite pure C++? He "newed" up an array, and that pretty much all that's not pure C about this code.

Comment: Could you describe the problem you are experiencing when running the code?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory for small arrays?  You could declare the arrays locally without using `operator new`.  This means you don't have worry about memory management.

Comment: @ForceBru: What is *pure* C++?  I haven't heard that term before.

Comment: There should be an existing *nix utility that splits files.  I don't remember the name of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should close output file after each loop iteration:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        sprintf(nfn, "%s.%d", fn, j);
        ft = fopen(nfn, "wb");
        fread(s1, 1, size_per_pack, f);
        fwrite(s1, 1, size_per_pack, ft);
        fclose(ft);
    }
```

Comment: I still have 0kb file.

Comment: @Phát Nguyễn You also have error in `fwrite(&s1, 1, size_per_pack, ft);`. See my corrected answer.

Comment: @Phát Nguyễn Function `fwrite` require `const void* ptr` as first argument. And you provide `char**` arg. Example of using `write` you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/).